# REST URL for a resource

Tags: rest, url, web

I have doubt since a long time regarding the URL link for resources like user and questions here on stack exchange sites. When I goto my profile page I expect something like:

`https://stackoverflow.com/users/codeyogi`

But I see:

`https://stackoverflow.com/users/4260745/codeyogi`

Why there is an extra random number? since the user names are unique.

Comment: If the number is indeed random, it can be an access request number. If the number is not random, then it probably is a unique key for the data of the user (looking for the data with a numeric key is a lot faster than with a string, usually).

Comment: 1. You seem to imply that Stack Exchange user profile URIs are created according to REST principles. Why? 2. It’s easy to check if usernames really are unique on Stack Exchange sites. See [Users](https://stackoverflow.com/users). There is even another user with your name: [CodeYogi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5679597/codeyogi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number is probably not random. It's the unique user ID of your account. The website probably wants to allow the same name for multiple people like "John" for example. However, John "A" is different from John "B" and the way to distinguish that is by a unique user ID.

Comment: I don't think you can have same user name here, can we?

Comment: When I registered my account it only asked me for an email and a password. I did not make a username at all. It asks for a "display name", an email address, and a password.

Comment: If the user name can be same and each user has unique id then why have the user name in the URL at all? There is already UID in the URL.

Comment: How? it has now both the components `id` and `username`. It was readable when there was only `username`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why there is an extra random number? since the user names are unique.

Because in REST, the spelling of the URL *doesn't matter*, so the server can encode any information it likes into it, where it likes, and change the scheme when it likes.

> I expect something like:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/users/codeyogi

That would also be a valid spelling.  But there's no reason for you, as the client, to care what spelling is going to be used -- you just follow links, and it all works.

Don't have an answer as to why stack exchange uses this particular spelling; [the apidocs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) hint that all of the uri templates make room for an ID, so maybe the usernames aren't unique across *time*?